# Fabric で今実行中の host を取得するには？

Tags: fabric

fabric で、今実行中の host を取得することはできますか？
具体的には、 get で localpath を自分で指定したくて、 host が含まれるようなローカルパスの指定方法がわからないと感じています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`env.host_string` がほしかったものでした。

```
from fabric.api import env

def some_task():
    print env.host_string
```